# Expo error only on phone: invariant violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a simple application with a context provider, when running the application on my phone using Expo application, it throws an error like in this photo

[image]

here is my app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import IndexScreen from "./src/screens/IndexScreen";
import {BlogProvider} from "./src/context/BlogContext";

const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Index: IndexScreen
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Index',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'Blog List'
  }
});
const App = createAppContainer(navigator);

export default () => {
  return <BlogProvider><App/></BlogProvider>;
}
```

and the blogContext.js file:

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

const BlogContext = React.createContext();
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add':
            return [...state, `Blog post #${state.length + 1}`]
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
export const BlogProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,[]);
    const addBlogPost = () => {
       dispatch({type: 'add'})
    }
    return <BlogContext.Provider value={{data: state, addBlogPosts: addBlogPost}}> {children} </BlogContext.Provider>
}
export default BlogContext;
```

I am seeing this error only on mobile, when opening the app in the browser it doesnt show any errors

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the return statement must be wrapped into parentheses like so:

```
 import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
const BlogContext = React.createContext();
const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add':
            return [...state, `Blog post #${state.length + 1}`]
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
export const BlogProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [blogPosts, dispatch] = useReducer(blogReducer,[]);
    const addBlogPost = () => {
       dispatch({type: 'add'})
    };
    return (
        <BlogContext.Provider value={{data: blogPosts, addBlogPost}}>
            {children}
        </BlogContext.Provider>
    );
};
export default BlogContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just wasted 3 hours of my life contemplating quitting code because of this.
This might be a possible solution for someone else.

I rewrote everything and I realized that my linter added a space before and after {children}.

i.e.:

```
//CORRECT
return (<UserContext.Provider value={{ userAuth, userDocument }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>);
//WRONG will give Error: Text string must be rendered...blah blah..
return (<UserContext.Provider value={{ userAuth, userDocument }}> {children} </UserContext.Provider>);
```